# Generator parallel same voltage maximum phase shift?

Tags: parallel, generator

Two gasoline generators rated 6.5kw and 9kw 240vac split phase. Voltage equalized.

Anyone could explain how the generators remain locked in synch after coupling? I believe is a sweet spot where the push-pull minimizes the power transfer between generators. Is that correct-and all there is?

How can I determine the power transfer function of phase shift? The house load could be minimal: 2kW.

Is there any other trigger than overload to decouple any of the two generators? Is there a fast decoupling?

Is there a way to detect the phase shift after coupling?

If the answers were already provided in another post, I apologize for asking again.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Measuring "phase" in one system without "reference" is not easy ... And what does "phase" relate to?

Comment: Phase means synchronicity. Phase shift means deviation from synchronicity between the bus AC and the AC off the generator incoming to the bus. Excepting for “split phase” that means “opposite phase”.